# Is it rude to point out the questioner couldn't possibly have checked existing answers before asking their question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, etiquette

Should we post comments pointing out how easily other existing questions and answers were found?

How about making fun of the questioner?

I often want to do both of these things, and in fact just before asking this I did post a comment just after my close request. I feel bad about it now, but on the other hand, will people ever learn to look before posting if the questions are closed without more commentary?

Comment: You at least provide links directly to said existing questions, yes?

Comment: @random: A "close as duplicate" automatically posts a comment with the question link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The option to close as a duplicate is kind of like saying "apparently you can't be bothered to search first, so stop wasting my time". It just comes off a little less abrasive than that.

So just vote to close as a dupe, and don't go through the effort to add insult to injury. Otherwise someone will soon be posting *"should I flag as offensive when someone calls me out for posting a dupe after already voting to close?"*

Comment: What happens when there are [more dupes than you can shake a stick at](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bphp%5d%20%22cannot%20modify%20header%22)?  It's hard to close-as-dupe when finding an appropriate dupe is a difficult task.

Comment: @Charles: if there are several, you can either go with 'follow the leader' and agree with the one chosen by the first person, or choose an alternative from the list that you think is better.  Which duplicate is chosen isn't dreadfully important if they are all actually duplicates.  There is probably one with better answers than the others so you you should try to choose that - but don't spend an inordinate amount of time on determining which that is.  (High votes may help show you which to use.)

Answer (score 4):

You can point out a list of other questions in a comment - that can be helpful.  If one (or more) is an exact duplicate, then suggest that as a close item.

However, I don't think it is fair game to point out how easily they were found - unless, perhaps, the questioner is an egregious repeat offender.  And certainly do not make fun of the questioner; that should earn your comment a 'flag'.